# How do I do a git merge that does nothing?

Tags: git

I want to create a commit that has N parents, but the final state of the code is identical to one of the N parents, leaving the current `HEAD` pointing to the new commit.

The purpose of this is set up a baseline for long-term merging on a maintenance branch. What command line arguments will do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a merge strategy.  The "ours" strategy is a good starting point.  Suppose you are on branch master:

```
git merge --strategy ours branch1 branch2 branch3
```

This will merge in branch1, branch2, and branch3, but the contents of the merge commit will be identical to the contents of the master branch prior to the commit.

Comment: The relevant documentation: [git-merge(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html).

Comment: FWIW, I've read it many times, but I find myself lost in the trees.